# How to change date in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe like below

```
     day
0  2016-07-12
1  2016-08-13
2  2016-09-14
3  2016-10-15
4  2016-11-01

dtype:datetime64
```

I would like to change the day like below

```
     day
0  2016-07-01
1  2016-08-01
2  2016-09-01
3  2016-10-01
4  2016-11-01
```

I tried

```
df.day.dt.day=1
```

but It didnt work well
How can I transform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `numpy`, first convert to `numpy array` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html) and then convert to `datetime64[M]` by [`astype`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html), what is the fastest solution:

```
df['day'] = df['day'].values.astype('datetime64[M]')
print (df)
         day
0 2016-07-01
1 2016-08-01
2 2016-09-01
3 2016-10-01
4 2016-11-01
```

---

Another slowier solution:

```
df['day'] = df['day'].map(lambda x: pd.datetime(x.year, x.month, 1))
print (df)
         day
0 2016-07-01
1 2016-08-01
2 2016-09-01
3 2016-10-01
4 2016-11-01
```

**Timings**:

```
#[50000 rows x 1 columns]
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

def f(df):
    df['day'] = df['day'].values.astype('datetime64[M]')
    return df

print (f(df))    

In [281]: %timeit (df['day'].map(lambda x: pd.datetime(x.year, x.month, 1)))
10 loops, best of 3: 160 ms per loop

In [282]: %timeit (f(df))
100 loops, best of 3: 4.38 ms per loop
```